# Is any tool for database schema comparison via C#

Tags: c#, database, schema-compare

I need to build job which will compare two databases and if there are some changes it should report about it.

I have found 
1) Red Gate API tool - too expensive
2) https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator - not exactly what I need
3) http://blog.apexsql.com/apexsql-diff-api-discontinued/ -  discontinued

So only 1 way is manually building some code for comparing sql objects? Please advice

Comment: No product recommendations. Otherwise: VISUAL STUDIO.´SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) can do that for years.

Comment: TomTom, the tool which you described I use for years, but it is not what I need. I need some nuget package or API which will help figuring out the differences in the code

Comment: I tried to do this very thing, and spent some 3 days reading about different approaches. In the end, I wrote my own tool which proved to be the most useful. Reading from the SYS tables (in MsSQL) and writing to an XML file of a known db, do the same on another, and then do a comparison of the XML nodes. Learning an API would mean less repeated effort, but I'm a big advocate of just writing it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) can compare databases and create XML file with differences.

It is the `diff` feature:
http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html